# SQL Error: No mapping exists to a known managed provider type

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm getting this error:

```
System.ArgumentException   HResult=0x80070057   Message=No mapping
exists from object type
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter,
System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] to a known managed provider native
type.   Source=&lt;Cannot evaluate the exception source&gt;
```

I've googled, and the examples are where someone tries to use an object instead of the text value for the `SqlParameter` value. Like, they try to use `someControl` instead of `someControl.Text`. In my case, below, `toStatus` and `fromStatus` are already strings. I'm not sure what else could be the problem. What am I missing?

```
public void UpdateStatus(SearchCriteria searchCriteria, string fromStatus, string toStatus)
{
  var sql = new StringBuilder();
  var sqlParameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

  sql.Append("UPDATE Schema.Table SET Status = @toStatus WHERE Status = @fromStatus");

  sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@toStatus", toStatus) { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar });
  sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fromStatus", fromStatus) { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar });

  db.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql.ToString(), sqlParameters);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExecuteSqlCommand` expects an array instead of a `List`.
Use as below

```
db.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql.ToString(), sqlParameters.ToArray());
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks. I'll accept as soon as SO lets me.